# Sorting list with extra arguments to comparison function

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

Given the following

```
class Coordinate {
  int i,j;
};

list<shared_ptr<Coordinate>> coordinates;
```

(`Coordinate` is just a much simpler version of what my code really contains.) I want to sort the `list` with respect to minimal Euclidean distance to a given coordinate `iCenter,jCenter`. The `Coordinate` which is closest to this coordinate should be at first position in the list `coordinates`. Furterhmore, I want to use following structure

```
struct ComparatorForCoordinate {
  bool operator() (const shared_ptr<Coordinate>& c1, const shared_ptr<Coordinate>& c2) {
    // return distance(c1 to center) > distance(c2 to center)
  }
};

// sorting:
coordinates.sort(ComparatorForCoordinate());
```

My problem is that my `operator()` needs to know the coordinate `iCenter,jCenter`. How can I pass these two double values to the comparison-function? The naive try just to let the operator additionally have two double parameters for the center position did not work. This call would be great for me if it would work:

```
coordinates.sort(ComparatorForCoordinate(iCenter,jCenter));
```

Comment: I've tweaked the title, and added the STL tag, in the hope that it will be easier for other users to find this question (and the answer).  Feel free to revert if you don't like the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add state to your comparator:

```
struct ComparatorForCoordinate {
  ComparatorForCoordinate(Coordinate center) : _center(center) {}

  bool operator() (const shared_ptr<Coordinate>& c1, const shared_ptr<Coordinate>& c2) const {
    return distance(c1, _center) > distance(c2, _center);
  }

private:
  Coordinate _center;
};

// sorting:
coordinates.sort(ComparatorForCoordinate(center));
```

Comment: This works...If I now got two different comparator-functions, e.g. one sorting according Euclidean distance and one only sorting according distance between the `i`-values. Do I need two `structs` as a Comparator or can I put these two comparison-functions in the same struct?

Comment: @Kapa11: You could add a `bool euclidean` argument to the comparator constructor and check it during every comparison.  But it would be more efficient and idiomatic to write a separate comparator.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's what i searched for :)